# Ajax control toolkit Html Editor paste image support

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm looking for asp.net editor control which support pasting image from clipboard. I saw in [asp.net froum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1744713.aspx?Pasting%20images%20into%20HTML%20Editor%20and%20Extender) that Html Editor or HtnlEditorExtender support pasting image from clipboard. But I couldn't figure it out. However, does this toolkit support this functionality or is there any other component which support it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No.
Ajax Control Toolkit HTML editors has no ability to paste an image from clipboard. This is purely browser behavior as you can read in the last post the thread you are referred to.